# Adjust Resize property does not work

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

My Problem here is as follow -

I have a `webview` in my activity and below that `webview`, a linear layout displaying the footer icons which are stick at the bottom.

Now when the soft keyboard pops up, I want the whole of the activity to adjust resize but I don't want the footer icons to come upside, I want them to stick to the bottom.

`AdjustPan` and `adjustNothing` are not working for me, as my webpage is containing `editTexts` for username and password and both these properties are making them stay behind the soft keypad.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

I want the floating buttons which are part of my Linear Layout to not come up when soft keyboard pop up.
My Xml is as below  -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rel_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rel_web">
            <WebView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/wv_main"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false">
            </WebView>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/offline_mode"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/offline"
                    android:id="@+id/im_offline" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:text="Offline"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/im_offline"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="47px"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.80"
                    android:weightSum="11.5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openHome"
                        android:src="@drawable/home_icon"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openHeadphone"
                        android:src="@drawable/headphone_icon" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openEmail"
                        android:src="@drawable/email_icon" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openFb"
                        android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openInsta"
                        android:src="@drawable/instagram_icon" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openYoutube"
                        android:src="@drawable/youtube" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml code.

Comment: Will you add your xml code

Comment: you need to share you layout file with question

Comment: post your xml.....buddy

Comment: See my edit, I have added the xml.

Comment: @B.shruti always try to use dp instead of px

Comment: @B.shruti check my answer and tell me if this is exactly you want ? Now your linear layout doesn't come up when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: @B.shruti I copied your entire xml file. I didn't set any adjustPan and adjustNothing properties. I also kept temporary EditText to popup softkeypad and loaded google.com. But Icons which are at bottom not came above the keybord. I checked with Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Comment: as @Abhishek told. this code works perfect for me also.

Comment: @B.shruti please check if you are setting some properties in Activity then you have to put activity code also.

Comment: @B.shruti check my updated answer and let me know if any

Comment: @B.shruti did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check on my way and i just remove `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and added at parent **`Scrollview`**. Try following code:

**Code**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rel_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_web"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wv_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:isScrollContainer="false" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/offline_mode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/im_offline"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/im_offline"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Offline"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />



            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.80"
                    android:weightSum="11.5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openHome"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openHeadphone"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openEmail"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openFb"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="29dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openInsta"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="openYoutube"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>



    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the screen shot I had checked.**

**Screen shot one**

[image]

**Screen shot two**

[image]

**Screen shot three** after i have scrolled down

[image]